# Болезнь творца или как создать свой виртуальный мир?

Tags: разработка-игр, циклы, архитектура

Приветствую всех в моем периоде жизни, в котором я решился взяться за свою давнюю мечту. Болезнь творца, или как создать свою виртуальную матрицу, не выходило из моей головы ровно столько, сколько я себя помню. И вот, после стольких отложенных попыток, набравшись массой знания и опыта, я рад что берусь за это дело всерьез.

**Мое знание**

- HTML, CSS
- Javascript, Jquery, Ajax
- PHP, ООП
- MySQL
- Фреймворк Laravel

[image: матрица]

Перейду к сути. Я хочу создать огромный виртуальный город, времен средневековья, который будет жить своей жизнью, независимо от меня. 3D графику позволить себе не могу, потому все будет пока что в виде обычных графиков и цифр, в дальнейшем придумаю визуальную оболочку всему этому.

Город будет иметь небольшие окрестности, в которых необходимо реализовать рост растительности и активность некой фауны.

Жителей в начала создам в количестве 1000 штук. Каждый должен иметь свой распорядок дня, позицию на карте, финансовые операции, добычу и затраты ресурсов. Реализую скрипт по непредвиденным обстоятельствам в виде отношений, свадеб, болезней, рождений, желаний и так далее.

Так же важной частью реализации станет экономика — примитивная экономика. Цены товаров и услуг будут назначаться в зависимости от спроса и количества.

**Итак вопросы**

В первую очередь, я нуждаюсь в абсолютно любой информации которая может мне помочь. Я буду сильно благодарен, если вы направите меня на что изучать и что будет полезно для реализации данной цели.

**Вопрос** - Раз мой город можно разделить по логическим вычислениям на экономику, поведения жителей, рост и активность фауны и так далее, я думаю а не разделить ли мне эти процессы по разным серверам. Один сервер будет вычислять рост деревьев, передвижения оленей по лесам, количества рыб в озерах, пока другой сервер занимается высчитыванием экономики. Будет некий промежуточный сервер, который будет собирать информацию с серверов и передавать пользователю. Что вы думаете об этом? Да и как бы вы реализовали общение между этими серверами?

**Вопрос** - Как вы знаете, есть одна проблема у скриптовых языков вроде PHP, они умирают сразу же после выполнения. А мне нужно что-то, что будет работать постоянно и заниматься постоянным вычислением. Первое что приходит мне в голову это CRON.

Предлагаю упростить все это дело для понимания до уровня Тамагочи. Есть человечек в MySQL. У этого человечка есть поле Голод. Каждую секунду, этот голод должен увеличиваться. Когда у персонажа голод заполнится, он должен тупо отправлять мне email. Каким образом мне каждую секунду проверять его на голод? Что посоветуете вы?

Опять же, внесу конкретику! Я хочу создать мир, который будет жить своей жизнью. Возьмем к примеру Cities Skyline. Если я запущу игру перед тем как отправится на работу, я буду знать, что там течет жизнь. Что в данный вот момент, определенный персонаж в игре проснулся, сел в свою машину, отправился куда-то и т.п.

Comment: Учите нормальные языки типа плюсов.

Comment: У вас хороший (с точки зрения познания) вопрос, но, он слишком общий для этого ресурса... Рекомендую найти какой нибудь форум, и попытаться решать проблему там, постепенно, разбивая всё на более простые шаги и решения.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов,  а чем `php` не нормальный язык? В своей сфере применения(веб) - получше плюсов будет.

Comment: @Klimenkomud а в сфере приложений, работающих тысячи часов подряд - не очень. Что у похапе с многопоточностью, кстати? С работой с сырыми BSD-сокетами?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sockets.php - вот вам `BSD-sockets`. https://habrahabr.ru/post/300952/ - а вот про многопоточность в "похапе"

Comment: Практически любое приложение, на любом языке может спокойно работать само по себе. его можно запускать например из скриптов запуска системы, т.е. вместе с сервером. или во время отладки просто в консоли. И это приложение будет постоянно считать то что ему требуется или спать, если ничего не требуется. все состояние оно может писать в БД и/или в какой нибудь кеш вроде memcached или просто в файлы. Если клиенты приходят их может отработать тот же php, который получит текущее состояние и отдаст клиенту, после чего завершится. но если клиента надо постоянно обновлять - то лучше  websocket

Comment: И от языка практически не зависит умирает он после выполнения или нет. просто так построена работа web-серверов (и то не всегда) что они запускают скрипт и потом он завершается. Но тот же php вы можете спокойно запустить в консоли и он будет работать постоянно. И кстати, есть например NodeJS в нем web-сервер по умолчанию встроен в сам движок и ваше приложение является само по себе постоянно запущенным web-серверов. Другое дело, что интенсивные вычисления действительно лучше писать на C, потому что он компилируемый и гораздо быстрее любого интерпретируемого языка